# Java immediately calling the method I initialized in the array

Tags: java, eclipse, webdriver

This is the sample code or the methods I'm trying to initialize:

```
    WebDriver launch_browser1()
    {
        // initialize driver stuff
        return driver;
    }

    WebDriver launch_browser2()
    {
        // initialize driver stuff
        return driver;
    }
```

This is the initialization code I have

```
WebDriver test_browsers [] = {launch_browser1(), launch_browser2()};
```

When I hit run, it's immediately calling the browsers I initialized

My current workaround is

```
public static String test_browsers[] = {"browser1", "browser2"};
for (int i = 0; i < test_browsers.length; i++) 
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        driver = launch_browser1();
    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
        driver = launch_browser2();
    }
}
```

My goal is to launch the browsers one at a time. The work around works just fine but I need help with the optimization of my current code. I'm not sure where I went wrong with the initialization but any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your two snippets have essentially the same behavior. Calling the two methods in a loop or calling them in an array expression will have no significant difference. What exactly is wrong with the first one? The two methods will be called immediately in both cases, and not concurrently in either case.

Comment: It seems you are not seeing that writing `launch_browser1()` in the array initialization means: execute `launch_browser1` method and put the returned object in the 0 position. It is behaving as you defined it. Maybe you have experience with some other languages where `launch_browser1()` executes a method and `launch_browser1` is a method reference.

Comment: @AleZalazar ooh. my bad. yeah youre right. this same code works well in python but when i tried with java, nope. will modify my code then post an update. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @zoenightshade, You can wrap the actual array initialization as lambdas. I have added an answer using `Supplier`

Comment: @Horse will check it out now. thank you so much. appreciate the help :D

Answer (score 0):

### Supplier

This problem cab be solved using the [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) in the Java

1. Create supplier and wrap the actual object creation inside the supplier
2. `Supplier.get()` will invoke lambda

```java
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class SupplierTest {

    public static class WebDriver {
        public WebDriver() {
            System.out.println("Initialized");
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println("Running " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }


    static WebDriver launch_browser1() {
        // initialize driver stuff
        return new WebDriver();
    }

    static WebDriver launch_browser2() {
        // initialize driver stuff
        return new WebDriver();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supplier<WebDriver> test_browsers [] = new Supplier[]{ () -> launch_browser1(), () -> launch_browser2()};
        for (Supplier<WebDriver> a : test_browsers) {
            System.out.println("Inside for loop");
            a.get().print();
        }
    }
}
```